# iPhone Safari and Chrome ignore JavaScript DOM changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, google-chrome, safari

Right now I have some JavaScript code that gets data from Parse.  When it is done getting the data, it appends it to a select box so my user can make further selections.  Here's my full code:

```
    Parse.Cloud.run("listEvents", {}, {
    success: function (results) {
        var listItems = buildOptionFromParse("", "Select a date");
        var today = new Date();
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var object = results[i];
            var eventDate = object.get("eventDate");
            var dateString = eventDate.getMonth() + 1 + "-" + eventDate.getDate() + "-" + eventDate.getFullYear();
            var eventDate = new Date(dateString);
            if (eventDate > today) {
                listItems += buildOptionFromParse(dateString, dateString);
            }
        }

        $("#date").html(listItems);
    },
    error: function (error) {
    }
});
```

buildOptionFromParse doesn't do anything special, just returns a string:

```
return "<option value='" + value + "'>" + label + "</option>";
```

Where listItems is a set of valid option strings.

This works fine on Chrome on desktop, IE on desktop, and Chrome on Android. The options appear in my select boxes as I would expect.  However, it does not work on Safari on iOS (I checked on a few versions as I have access to Perfecto for mobile testing).

The other strange thing I found is that I tried on Chrome for iPhone, thinking that'd be just fine.  Nope, same thing.  The options do not populate.

Kind of at a loss at this point. I'm using JQuery 1.11.3 and just updated to it after reading that this problem could be caused by the version of JQuery I was on.  didn't fix it though.

Comment: Error in console? You should btw provide more context in question itself regarding how do you call this code and what is `listItems`?

Comment: I have not been able to find an error in the console.  I'm an Android user, and only have access to iPhone via a simulator which does not have a console.  if I had that I'd probably have this fixed already. :)